# Usage of Enum in NestJs Project

Tags: typescript, enums, nestjs

I was trying to use Enum in my simple project. But I don't like the way I am calling enum values for some reason. Example Here; I am trying to create my custom pipe.

```
import { BadRequestException, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TaskStatus } from '../task.model';
export class TaskStatusValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  readonly allowedStatus = [
    TaskStatus.OPEN,
    TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
    TaskStatus.DONE,
  ];
  transform(value: any) {
    value = value.toUpperCase();
    if (!this.isStatusValid(value)) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`'${value}' is not valid status`);
    }
    return value;
  }
  private isStatusValid(status: any) {
    const idx = this.allowedStatus.indexOf(status);
    console.log(idx);
    return idx !== -1;
  }
}
```

I don't like that part :

> ```
> export class TaskStatusValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
>       readonly allowedStatus = [
>         TaskStatus.OPEN,
>         TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
>         TaskStatus.DONE,
>       ];
> ```

There is any logical way to assign my valid statuses in an array that **allowedStatus** as above but with a simple way instead of calling per status from TaskStatus(like,**`TaskStatus.OPEN`**...)? Because; for big projects, I might have a lot of valid statuses in TaskStatus(like 'OPEN', 'DONE', 'DECLINED'...etc).

Also, it is TaskStatus enum :

```
export enum TaskStatus {
  OPEN = 'OPEN',
  IN_PROGRESS = 'IN_PROGRESS',
  DONE = 'DONE',
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I assume the incoming `value` _should_ be a valid enum status, correct? `'OPEN'`, `'IN_PROGRESS'`, `'DONE'`, etc?

Comment: Yes, actually I am trying to update status of some objects so I need to check new status is valid status or not ? Valid statuses are in my my enum which TaskStatus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the incoming value should already be an enum value, why couldn't you do something like

```js
  private isStatusValid(status: keyof typeof TaskStatus) {
    const value = TaskStatus[status];
    return !!value;
  }
```

This should return the turthy value of the `TaskStatus[status]` (i.e. if the incoming status does not map to an enum value it's falsy)

Comment: That's awesome! May I know there is any way to call enum values in an array with less code I mean not call like `TaskStatus.OPEN` ?

Comment: I do this in one of my projects doing `Enum[Enum[enumValue]]`, essentially double referencing the enum. It's dynamic, but you gotta understand how enums get compiled to JS to see how it works properly

Comment: Thanks for all of your good answers, I was looking for something like that :

`export const new_arr = [];
for (const value in TaskStatus) {
  new_arr.push(value);
}`